# Type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here's the variable I took

```
int _bmi = 0;
```

And this is where I used typecast

```
actions: [
  TextButton(
    child: const Text('Approve'),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        int sum = int.parse(massNumber.text) + int.parse(heightNumber.text);
        _bmi = sum.toString() as int;
      });
    },
  ),
]
```

On running the program, I'm getting an error:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in typecast

Comment: why not like _bmi = sum ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you intended is equal to `_bmi = sum`

Answer (score 1):

Simply, `_bmi = int.parse(massNumber.text) + int.parse(heightNumber.text);`

Answer (score 0):

just do `_bmi=sum`

don't convert sum to string and then cast as int its wrong